# mysql num rows on mysql fetch object

Tags: php, mysql

```
function sql_obj($q){
    $result = new stdClass();
    $r = mysql_query_ex($q);
    if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
        $o = mysql_fetch_object($r);
        $result = $o;
    }
    return $result;
} 
$o = sql_obj($q);
```

How can I get number of rows?

I was using `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { // do stuff`.

What is option on this code?

Comment: What is mysql_query_ex function ?

Comment: Did you read the [manual](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows)? `mysql_num_rows()` expects a mysql result handle as its argument. In your code, `$result` is just an empty object and has NOTHING to do with mysql.

Comment: How then i can get number of rows by $result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 function sql_obj($q){
     $result = new stdClass();
     $r = mysql_query_ex($q);
     if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
        $o = mysql_fetch_assoc($r); // result will be in array type.
        $result = $o;
     }
     return $result;
 } 
 $o = sql_obj($q);


 if(count($result) > 0) { // do stuff }
```

Comment: Thank for idea. I just use if($o->id) { / stuff }

Answer (score 0):

```
function sql_obj($q){
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    return mysql_num_rows($r);
} 
$o = sql_obj($q);
```

return `mysql_num_rows()`, not the data from database.